# Find and replace IR code

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace

Hi I am having a bit of trouble with the code below. I want to replace every digit in a `.txt` file with an IR code. I am running windows 10 64bit.

IR codes from numbers `0` to `9`.

```
REM 0 - 0x1067728D
REM 1 - 0x106742BD
REM 2 - 0x1067827D
REM 3 - 0x106702FD
REM 4 - 0x1067629D
REM 5 - 0x1067A25D
REM 6 - 0x106722DD
REM 7 - 0x106752AD
REM 8 - 0x1067926D
REM 9 - 0x106712ED
```

I dug up a find and replace script from [here](http://www.dostips.com/?t=batch.findandreplace) and created a loop for every number, however the `output.txt` looks like this: ↓

```
 {00883}  {0080x106712ED-4}  {0080x106712ED-5}  {0080x106712ED-0x106712ED-}  {00887}  {00888}
```

Instead of like this: ↓

```
 {0x1067728D-0x1067728D-0x1067926D-0x1067926D-0x106702FD}  {0x1067728D-0x1067728D-0x1067926D-0x1067926D-0x1067629D}  {0x1067728D-0x1067728D-0x1067926D-0x1067926D-0x1067A25D}  {0x1067728D-0x1067728D-0x1067926D-0x1067926D-0x106722DD}  {0x1067728D-0x1067728D-0x1067926D-0x1067926D-0x106752AD}  {0x1067728D-0x1067728D-0x1067926D-0x1067926D-0x1067926D}
```

The input file looks like this: ↓

```
{00883}  {00884}  {00885}  {00886}  {00887}  {00888}
```

This is the code I am using any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
::CallScript
@echo off
CALL :Script0
CALL :Script1
CALL :Script2
CALL :Script3
CALL :Script4
CALL :Script5
CALL :Script6
CALL :Script7
CALL :Script8
CALL :Script9
pause
goto :eof

:Script0
@echo off
set "NewStr=0x1067728D-"
set "InFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\In.txt"
set "OutPutFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\Out.txt"
Call :FindReplace "" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%"
set "OldStr=0"
Call :FindReplace "%OldStr%" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%" "%OutPutFile%"

:FindReplace <OldStr> <NewStr> <InFile> <OutPutFile>
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
(
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
        set "line=%%B"
        if defined line (
            call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
            for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
        ) ELSE echo.
    )
)>%4
goto :eof

:Script1
@echo off
set "NewStr=0x106742BD-"
set "InFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\In.txt"
set "OutPutFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\Out.txt"
Call :FindReplace "" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%"
set "OldStr=1"
Call :FindReplace "%OldStr%" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%" "%OutPutFile%"

:FindReplace <OldStr> <NewStr> <InFile> <OutPutFile>
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
(
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
        set "line=%%B"
        if defined line (
            call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
            for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
        ) ELSE echo.
    )
)>%4
goto :eof

:Script2
@echo off
set "NewStr=0x1067827D-"
set "InFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\In.txt"
set "OutPutFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\Out.txt"
Call :FindReplace "" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%"
set "OldStr=2"
Call :FindReplace "%OldStr%" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%" "%OutPutFile%"

:FindReplace <OldStr> <NewStr> <InFile> <OutPutFile>
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
(
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
        set "line=%%B"
        if defined line (
            call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
            for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
        ) ELSE echo.
    )
)>%4
goto :eof

:Script3
@echo off
set "NewStr=0x106702FD-"
set "InFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\In.txt"
set "OutPutFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\Out.txt"
Call :FindReplace "" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%"
set "OldStr=3"
Call :FindReplace "%OldStr%" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%" "%OutPutFile%"

:FindReplace <OldStr> <NewStr> <InFile> <OutPutFile>
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
(
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
        set "line=%%B"
        if defined line (
            call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
            for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
        ) ELSE echo.
    )
)>%4
goto :eof

:Script4
@echo off
set "NewStr=0x1067629D-"
set "InFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\In.txt"
set "OutPutFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\Out.txt"
Call :FindReplace "" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%"
set "OldStr=4"
Call :FindReplace "%OldStr%" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%" "%OutPutFile%"

:FindReplace <OldStr> <NewStr> <InFile> <OutPutFile>
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
(
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
        set "line=%%B"
        if defined line (
            call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
            for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
        ) ELSE echo.
    )
)>%4
goto :eof

:Script5
@echo off
set "NewStr=0x1067A25D-"
set "InFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\In.txt"
set "OutPutFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\Out.txt"
Call :FindReplace "" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%"
set "OldStr=5"
Call :FindReplace "%OldStr%" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%" "%OutPutFile%"

:FindReplace <OldStr> <NewStr> <InFile> <OutPutFile>
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
(
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
        set "line=%%B"
        if defined line (
            call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
            for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
        ) ELSE echo.
    )
)>%4
goto :eof

:Script6
@echo off
set "NewStr=0x106722DD-"
set "InFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\In.txt"
set "OutPutFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\Out.txt"
Call :FindReplace "" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%"
set "OldStr=6"
Call :FindReplace "%OldStr%" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%" "%OutPutFile%"

:FindReplace <OldStr> <NewStr> <InFile> <OutPutFile>
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
(
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
        set "line=%%B"
        if defined line (
            call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
            for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
        ) ELSE echo.
    )
)>%4
goto :eof

:Script7
@echo off
set "NewStr=0x106752AD-"
set "InFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\In.txt"
set "OutPutFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\Out.txt"
Call :FindReplace "" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%"
set "OldStr=7"
Call :FindReplace "%OldStr%" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%" "%OutPutFile%"

:FindReplace <OldStr> <NewStr> <InFile> <OutPutFile>
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
(
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
        set "line=%%B"
        if defined line (
            call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
            for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
        ) ELSE echo.
    )
)>%4
goto :eof

:Script8
@echo off
set "NewStr=0x1067926D-"
set "InFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\In.txt"
set "OutPutFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\Out.txt"
Call :FindReplace "" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%"
set "OldStr=8"
Call :FindReplace "%OldStr%" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%" "%OutPutFile%"

:FindReplace <OldStr> <NewStr> <InFile> <OutPutFile>
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
(
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
        set "line=%%B"
        if defined line (
            call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
            for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
        ) ELSE echo.
    )
)>%4
goto :eof

:Script9
@echo off
set "NewStr=0x106712ED-"
set "InFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\In.txt"
set "OutPutFile=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\MDVR IR numbers\Out.txt"
Call :FindReplace "" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%"
set "OldStr=9"
Call :FindReplace "%OldStr%" "%NewStr%" "%InFile%" "%OutPutFile%"

:FindReplace <OldStr> <NewStr> <InFile> <OutPutFile>
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
(
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
        set "line=%%B"
        if defined line (
            call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
            for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
        ) ELSE echo.
    )
)>%4
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, your code is incredible too long.
You know about functions, but you don't use them in a proper way.

The second problem is, that you always replace something in your input file and create a new output file, but you want to replace incrementally.

The next problem is, that the order of replacing numbers to other numbers can't work, as you replace all `0` with `0x1067728D` and then you try to replace all `1` with `0x106742BD`, but this will also replace the `1` in the prior `0x1067728D`.

You have to replace first all numbers to something other, that will not occour in your replace expressions(I choose `MNOPQRSTUV`).
And then you can replace the letters with your desired expressions.

```
@echo off
set "InFile=In.txt"
set "OutPutFile=Out.txt"

copy "%InFile%" "%OutPutFile%"
CALL :replace   0   M
CALL :replace   1   N
CALL :replace   2   O
CALL :replace   3   P
CALL :replace   4   Q
CALL :replace   5   R    
CALL :replace   6   S
CALL :replace   7   T
CALL :replace   8   U
CALL :replace   9   V

CALL :replace   M   "0x1067728D,"
CALL :replace   N   "0x106742BD,"
CALL :replace   O   "0x1067827D,"
CALL :replace   P   "0x106702FD,"
CALL :replace   Q   "0x1067629D,"
CALL :replace   R   "0x1067A25D,"
CALL :replace   S   "0x106722DD,"
CALL :replace   T   "0x106752AD,"
CALL :replace   U   "0x1067926D,"
CALL :replace   V   "0x106712ED,"
CALL :replace   ",}"   }
goto :eof

:replace
@echo off
set "OldStr=%~1"
set "NewStr=%~2"
Call :FindReplace "%OldStr%" "%NewStr%" "%OutPutFile%"
exit /b

:FindReplace <OldStr> <NewStr> <InFile> <OutPutFile>
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS, DisableDelayedExpansion
rem if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
(
    for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" %3') do (
        set "line=%%A"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "line=!line:*:=!"
        if defined line (
            set "line=!line:%~1=%~2!"
        )
        (echo(!line!)
        endlocal
    )
) > TEMPFILE.tmp
del "%~3"
move TEMPFILE.tmp "%~3"
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks jeb, lets say that I wanted to replace the `-` behind `0x1067728D-` with a `,` how would I do that since this specific code doesn't allow `"&<>|^", ` ?

Comment: @Jonas I enclosed them in quotes, and changed `set "OldStr=%1"` to `set "OldStr=%~1"`. This also works with `&<>|`

Comment: @Jonas I enclosed them in quotes, and changed `set "OldStr=%1"` to `set "OldStr=%~1"`. This also works with `&<>|` but still not for `^!"` (There is a bit more work necessary)

Answer (score 2):

So first I'm not that good in batch so I can't help you really with that.
I make it in powershell when you can use this it's much easier.

```
$reparr =   '0x1067728D','0x106742BD','0x1067827D','0x106702FD','0x1067629D','0x1067A25D','0x106722DD','0x106752AD','0x1067926D','0x106712ED'
$output = ""
$input = "{00883}  {00884}  {00885}  {00886}  {00887}  {00888}"
foreach ($c in $input.ToCharArray()){
    try{
        $c = [int]([string]$c)
        $c = $reparr[$c]
        $output += $c + "-"
    } Catch {
        $output += $c
    }
}
$output.replace("-}","}")
```

Output:

```
{0x1067728D-0x1067728D-0x1067926D-0x1067926D-0x106702FD}  {0x1067728D-0x1067728D-0x1067926D-0x1067926D-0x1067629D}  {0x1067728D-0x1067728D-0x1067926D-0x1067926D-0x1067A25D}  {0x1067728D-0x1067728D-0x1067926D-0x1067926D-0x106722DD}  {0x1067728D-0x1067728D-0x1067926D-0x1067926D-0x106752AD}  {0x1067728D-0x1067728D-0x1067926D-0x1067926D-0x1067926D}
```

Also when you can't do it in powershell it should give you a hint how you can do it easier.
Because in your example you often duplicate your code and that's really a bad code quality.

Comment: Nice solution, even that's only powershell

Comment: Yeah I like your code too.
But I'm not that good in batch and I like powershell more.
And to give an advise how to do it easier and not that complicated it should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
:: data-input file
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q41118105.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 CALL :REPL "%%a" 0 m 1 n 2 o 3 p 4 q 5 r 6 s 7 t 8 u 9 v m 0x1067728D- n 0x106742BD- o 0x1067827D- p 0x106702FD- q 0x1067629D- r 0x1067A25D- s 0x106722DD- t 0x106752AD- u 0x1067926D- v 0x106712ED- -} }
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:REPL
SET "outdata=%~1"
:repll
SHIFT
IF "%2"=="" ECHO %outdata%&GOTO :EOF
CALL SET "outdata=%%outdata:%1=%2%%"
SHIFT
GOTO repll
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q41118105.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Picking up `jeb`'s lead, this solution reads the input file, and delivers the line, but quoted + each pair of substitutions to the subroutine.

The subroutine picks the first item and removes the quotes, then serially substitutes for the next parameter with the one after, disposing of the used parameters byy using `shift` until there are none left, when the result is `echo`ed.